# How to use clang thread sanitizer on OSX?

Tags: macos, clang, thread-sanitizer

I am trying to use `--thread-sanitizer` option of clang on OSX:

```
$ clang++ -fthread-sanitizer -fpic tsan1.cc
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix
[...]
clang -cc1 version 4.2 based upon LLVM 3.2svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
[...]
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___tsan_func_entry", referenced from:
      threadfunc(void*) in tsan1-6f7gbr.o
[...]
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Looks like a linkage error.  Should I link with some additional libs?

Comment: Found a bug in macports: http://trac.macports.org/ticket/38528 , must be not fixed yet

Answer (score 2):

ThreadSanitizer is unsupported on Darwin for C++ yet. This is unlikely to change in at least half a year.

Comment: Any sources for this?

Comment: This answer is obsolete. ThreadSanitizer has run on macOS for years.

Answer (score 1):

It's been fixed.
According to https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html

> ThreadSanitizer is supported on the following OS:
>   ... Darwin arm64, x86_64, ...

Also I just used it without any problems.